# Power Apps Code - Delegation warning fix (For SharePoint List)

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

I am getting a delegation warning for the function `SortByColumn()`

I know that as my list grows beyond 2k records that client side functions can start to break. IS there a way I can write this code to 1) Remove the warnings and 2) Accomplish the same thing with server side functions?

```
If(Toggle1_1.Value = true,Filter(If(Dropdown1_2.SelectedText.Value = "ALL",(If(Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value = "ALL", SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), 
Filter(SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value in priority.Value))), Filter((If(Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value = "ALL", SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), 
Filter(SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value in priority.Value))), Dropdown1_2.SelectedText.Value in request_type.Value)),Office365Users.UserProfile(User().Email).DisplayName in assignedto.DisplayName),If(Dropdown1_2.SelectedText.Value = "ALL",(If(Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value = "ALL", SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), 
Filter(SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value in priority.Value))), Filter((If(Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value = "ALL", SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), 
Filter(SortByColumns(help_desk_it,"Created",filterpump), Dropdown1_3.SelectedText.Value in priority.Value))), Dropdown1_2.SelectedText.Value in request_type.Value)))
```